# Play wav file on a mac, stock python

Tags: python, audio

Was just wondering if there is a simple way to play wav files on a mac woth stock python. If not what is a good module. My other problem is that I have to write the code on my school computer, on this computer it blocks things from unidentified developers. So i need a legit audio module.
Thanks

Comment: Check [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Comment: Sadly my computer says PyAudio is from an unidentified developer so I can't use it.

Comment: It's open source. Check if it relies on some other libraries and if not, just clone the source and compile it on your own computer/use directly in your project.

Comment: Is there a guide on how to do this?

Comment: See http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html and google `git clone` if you don't know how to clone from a git repo.

Comment: Oh well, you can't go the install route because it will ask for root permissions which you don't have.

Comment: Well... crap... I will see what I can do maybe Ill "obtain" root.

Comment: BTW PortAudio relies on [Alsa Project](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) so you need that too :/ See [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html)

Comment: Your computer says PyAudio is from an unidentified developer? Sounds as you are on OS X. You can control your [Gatekeer options](http://support.apple.com/en-en/HT202491)!